# Exp:resso Store 3D Secure Integration

Tags: expresso-store

My client has asked to integrate 3D Secure with their Exp:resso Store installation.

I have been searching and found that in the change log this has been added for SagePay in the UK. This is who the client is using.

Changelog: https://exp-resso.com/docs/store/release_notes.html#store_150

I can't find anywhere in the docs how to implement this. Does anyone know how? Is it a setting on SagePay side? Or is it a parameter I need to add in the checkout form?

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Got it! The setting is in SagePay itself: Settings > 3D Secure > Turn On and set rules.